# How can I "inform" my web application via web.xml that I have a configuration file regarding Spring Webflow?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I am writing a web application in Java 8. I use Maven and I included the dependencies regarding Spring Webflow in my Project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I use Form-based authentication and my web.xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="PROJECT" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">

        <display-name>PROJECT</display-name>

    /* 
    *   Somewhere here should I insert something in order to have
    *   my web application informed, that there is a spring-webflow-config.xml
    *   configuration file. How do I do this?
    */

        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>WEB-INF/firstPage.xhtml</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

        <security-constraint>
            <display-name>Constraint</display-name>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name></web-resource-name>
                <description />
                <url-pattern>/flows/*</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>

            <auth-constraint>
                <description />
                <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
                <role-name>USER</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>

        </security-constraint>

        <login-config>
            <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
            <realm-name>file</realm-name>
            <form-login-config>
                <form-login-page>WEB-INF/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
                <form-error-page>WEB-INF/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
            </form-login-config>
        </login-config>

        <security-role>
            <description>Administration</description>
            <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        </security-role>
        <security-role>
            <description>User</description>
            <role-name>USER</role-name>
        </security-role>

    </web-app>
```

I have also created the configuration for spring webflows and I seved it with the name "WEB-INF\config\spring-webflow-config.xml" and it looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"

xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd">


<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Webflow Configuration -->
<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" />

<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry">
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/WEB-INF/flows/*-flow/*-flow.xml" />
</webflow:flow-registry>

<bean id="flowMappings"
    class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
</bean>
```

In the code above I declare the folder/url-pattern I want to follow for my webflows

`/WEB-INF/flows/*-flow/*-flow.xml`

The question is, **how do I manage to inform my web application that there is a configuration regarding `spring webflow`?**

I looked up a lot of examples and tutorials, but for some funny reason noone explains

a)in which folder should each configuration file be put, neither

b)what is the name that the configuration files should have, in order to be recognised from `Spring Webflow` framework.

In case you know how is it possible to "inform" my web application about `Spring Webflow`, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't particularly matter where you put the webflow configuration file, you just tell the Spring DispatcherServlet:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/config/spring-webflow-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And it may not be obvious, but it's the Spring MVC setup, which is described by this section of the official WebFlow documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/spring-mvc.html#spring-mvc-config-web.xml